# Black status bar bug iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

everybody.

Guys, I have a problem with status bar in my project..

In default , in app status bar should hidden. This is work, but one view have a bug with status bar like on screenshot.
On main menu it's have black color and don't hidden(

In singleton I'm initialise background image for different devices, and this is work for all views in app))

This is my code singleton init background:

// background return
    - (UIColor *)mainBackground:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

```
    UIColor *color;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundIpad.png"]];
        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundLandspIpad.png"]];
        }
    } else {
        color = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
    }
    return color;
}

//return wight screen
- (float)wightScreen {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            return 768;
        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            return 1024;
        }
    }
    return wight();
}

//return rect view all for screens
- (CGRect)refreshPoints {
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
            return CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
            return CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        }
    } else {
        return CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, height());
    }
    return CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024);
}
```

And this is code in controller view, where I'm have a problem:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    return [[Singleton sharedInstance] getSelf:@"MainMenuController"];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[PostRequest sharedInstance] userInfo];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [[Singleton sharedInstance] mainBackground:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];

//    if (iphone4()) {
//        [self newRectNiewIphone];
//    }
}
```

I'm hope in yours help!

Answer (score 0):

This is screenshot with bug status bar

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfiZ3.png

And screenshot, how on another views

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVadC.png

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

On the viewController in the viewDidLoad method.